# How can I retrieve and use firebase data in a Google Cloud Function written in typescript?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

## Problem

I have a document on Firebase stored with the following structure seen below.

From a Google Cloud Function written in **typescript**, I would like to access and use the JSON data stored in my Firebase project. I am unsure of the correct syntax to use.

Firebase Document structure:

```
"users": {
    "tim": {
        "score": 1200
         "health": 200
         "items": {
            123123,
            182281,
            123344,
         }
     }
    "james": {
        "score": 100
         "health": 50
         "items": {
            143553,
            567454,
         }
     }
}
```

I currently retrieve the data from Firebase using the following code.

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export class ScoreHandler {
    constructor(private firestore: FirebaseFirestore.Firestore) {}

async calculateFinalScore(name: string): Promise<number> {
    try{
        const document = await this.firestore
          .collection("users")
          .doc("users")
          .get();
        
        // Check if record exists
        if (document.data() === undefined) {
           throw console.warn("unable to find users document data);
        }
        
        //!!THIS IS WRONG!! not sure how to read in and access this data?
        const score: number = document.data()["users"]["tim"]["score"];
        const health: number = document.data()["users"]["tim"]["health"];
        const items: Array<number> = document.data()["users"]["tim"]["items"];

        //Calculate Final score using score, health and items
        const finalScore: number = score * health * items.length;
        return finalScore;
        
    } catch (e) {
        // Log the Error on the Console
        console.error(e);
        return 0.0;
    }
    
}
```

I am unsure of the correct syntax to access data from a document snapshot in Typescript. I would like to be able to get the score, health and array of items from my firebase project into my cloud function class.

Any help is greatly Appreciated.
Thanks!

I have tried to get the data but keep getting object is possibly undefined errors and am unable to actually get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the data you can use the `data()` method on the snapshot object. This method returns the data in the document as an object.

You are using the `data()` method to get the data in the document snapshot, but you are not using the correct property names to access the data. The `data()` method returns an object, not a JSON object. Therefore, you need to use the correct property names for the object.

Try to access the score property of the tim object like this:

```js
const score: number = document.data()["users"]["tim"]["score"];
```

The correct way to access the score property in the JavaScript object returned by the data() method would look like this:

```js
const score: number = document.data()["tim"]["score"];
```

To access the other properties in the tim object, you would use the following syntax:

```js
const health: number = document.data()["tim"]["health"];
const items: Array<number> = document.data()["tim"]["items"];
```

Here is how your `calculateFinalScore()` method should look like using the correct syntax to access the data in the Firestore document snapshot:

```js
async calculateFinalScore(name: string): Promise<number> {
  try{
    const document = await this.firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc("users")
      .get();

    // Check if record exists
    if (document.data() === undefined) {
      throw console.warn("unable to find users document data");
    }

    // Get the score, health and items from the document snapshot
    const score: number = document.data()["tim"]["score"];
    const health: number = document.data()["tim"]["health"];
    const items: Array<number> = document.data()["tim"]["items"];

    // Calculate Final score using score, health and items
    const finalScore: number = score * health * items.length;
    return finalScore;
  } catch (e) {
    // Log the Error on the Console
    console.error(e);
    return 0.0;
  }
}
```

The name of the user is hardcoded as "tim". If you want to access the data for a different user, you will need to replace the "tim" property name with the name of the user that you want to access. Like:

```
const score: number = document.data()["james"]["score"];
const health: number = document.data()["james"]["health"];
const items: Array<number> = document.data()["james"]["items"];
```